# Gmail not showing full email message and shows Email Clipped

Tags: php, email, gmail, publish-subscribe

I have a newsletter designed for website which I send to all subscribers of my website. But at recievers end the message is getting clipped and isn't showing full message. User have to click on link to see full message. I want this email message to be shown in same page and dont want this message to get clipped. Email consists of images and description about the images.

What can I do to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you sending this? Is your HTML code valid? Have you tested the newsletter against guidelines for gmail etc?

Comment: Yes Its valid. Emails are getting successfully sent. The only problem is that the message gets clipped . To see full message it redirect me to other page.

Comment: This happens if you use an email client like outlook as well? Can you show us a preview?

Comment: I am using php mailer function

Comment: " [Message clipped]  View entire message " This message is shown at the end of the mail.

Comment: Does this happen to all recipients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through certain solutions and problem I found was with the size of HTML newsletter. 
If your email exceeds 102K, Gmail will display the first 102K and then it will clip off the remainder with a few different variations depending on the device.

So to avoid this problem try to keep your design of HTML letter within the limit by removing unnecessary code.

Hope it will help others too.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the format from

```
<!--<![endif]-->
```

to

```
<!-- &lt;!&ndash;&ndash; <![endif]&ndash;&ndash;&gt;-->
```